# How to configure 4 point lights to generate different shadows

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, light

I am using the cycles render and I have a 4 point lights attached at the same height of a cube scene. I have an object at the center of the scene and I need to configure the lights such that they generate different shadows (gradually darker). Any help?

[image]
Result:
Here, we can see the shadows but they are not very sharp because there are a lot of luminosity as in a real case, but is there any possibility to use different intensities to generate different dark shadows?
[image]

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you are going for. Do you think you could make some kind of illustration, or at least show us the scene?

Comment: @GiantCowFilms, I edit my question. I think that we can do it by generating different intensity for each light. So, the light having higher intensity will generate darker shadow.

Comment: Try it then? Show us your result...... what is wrong with the result?